# Access second drive in ReadyNAS system

Tags: readynas

I have a ReadyNAS file server with two 1-terabyte drives. I had planned the second one to just mirror the first one as a backup. But I now have a need for a lot of additional storage space so I'd like to use it for files. I don't see how to access it at all.

Comment: If it's already configured for mirroring, you will need to reconfigure as independent discs using the web interface. This may lose all the currently stored data, so you'll need to back up first.

Comment: Do you mean all the data on both drives? Or just the mirror?

Comment: To reconfigure as @AFH suggested will "destroy" the current RAID configuration, which is mirrored.  It is quite likely that you will lose ALL data by doing this, and then you will start off with 2 x **Blank** 1TB disks instead of 1 x 1 TB mirrored with all your data.  So before changing RAID configuration .... back up

Comment: As @DaríoMartín says, the data in a RAID configuration are in a format that cannot be interpreted outside RAID, so yes, you will lose all the data when you remove RAID. I haven't used all the RAID types, but it is true of RAID1, your most likely configuration. To be honest, I wouldn't sacrifice the security of RAID in order to get more disc space: I'd buy bigger discs. You need to check the specifications of your NAS, but I'd expect it to support up to 2TB discs at least. Your current discs can be put in USB cradles for off-line back-up. In any case, you'll need these to migrate the data.